# Display all rows returned by SQL query in a div

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, innerhtml

I'm trying to output the result of my SQL query to a `div` using the `InnerHTML`. but I can't get more than one record to show up. How do I make it so that all of my records are displayed in the `DIV`? On my page I have the `DIV` contained within a `UpdatePanel`and I only 1 row is displayed even when the query returns more than one row.

```
string sql = "Select * From Events";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
conn.Open();
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    divout1.InnerHtml += "Name: " + reader["Name"].ToString() + "<br />" +
        "Date: " + reader["Date"].ToString() + "<br />" +
        "Location: " + reader["Location"].ToString() + "<br />";
    divout.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: By any chance are showing divout instead of divout1?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but you need to escape the strings from the database before you put them in the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at first look, unless your query returns only one row, it should get all data on your div.

try to put a break point on the last bracket of your while statement and see what happens on your div after first iteration.

for other way, try to put the div out of the updatepanel to see what appens?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `StringBuilder` to build your sql and then output the contents of the `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
string sql = "Select * From Events";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
conn.Open();
reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    sb.AppendLine("Name: " + reader["Name"].ToString() + "<br />" +
        "Date: " + reader["Date"].ToString() + "<br />" +
        "Location: " + reader["Location"].ToString() + "<br />");
}

if(sb.Length > 0) {
    divout.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
    divout.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try something like this, may be concatenating inside the InnerHtml is screwing up or something.  also be sure you really have more than one row.

```
    var sb = new StringBuilder();  
    var formatString = "Name: {0} <br />Date: {1}<br />Location: {2}<br />"; 
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        sb.AppendFormat(formatString, reader["Name"].ToString(), reader["Date"].ToString(), reader["Location"].ToString());
    }
    divout1.InnerHtml = sb.Tostring();
    divout1.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
            string sql = "Select * From Events";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            conn.Open();
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            string s = string.Empty;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                s += "Name: " + reader["Name"].ToString() + "<br />" +
                    "Date: " + reader["Date"].ToString() + "<br />" +
                    "Location: " + reader["Location"].ToString() + "<br />";

            }
            divout1.innerHtml = s;
            divout1.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Although using a StringBuilder is better

Answer (score 0):

You should probably encode the strings coming from the Database since you're directly outputting it as raw HTML.

```
divout1.InnerHtml += "Name: " + Server.HtmlEncode(reader["Name"].ToString()) + "<br />" 
                   + "Date: " + Server.HtmlEncode(reader["Date"].ToString()) + "<br />"  
                   + "Location: " + Server.HtmlEncode(reader["Location"].ToString()) + "<br />";
```

see [HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx)